# python global variable not changing in recursive function

Tags: python, json, recursion, flask, global-variables

So I have a flask application that basically facilitates editing a json file. I ingest that json file, turn it in to an OrderedDict and then allow the user to edit it in the browser. Because of the funkiness of the editor I am using the user must only edit one "sub_system" at a time so I have a recursive function to find which subsystem they have edited and changes that one on the global variable.

```
def update_dict_with_edits(main_dict, changed_dict):
    if changed_dict["name"] == main_dict["name"]:
        space_system_dict = changed_dict
        return
    if "sub_systems" not in main_dict:
        return
    for sub_system in main_dict["sub_systems"]:
        update_dict_with_edits(sub_system, changed_dict)
```

It is called here:

```
@app.route('/updatedict', methods=['POST'])
def update_dict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        changed_json_system = request.form.get('json_data', None)
        changed_dict_system = json.loads(changed_json_system, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
        # the_dict_object.the_json is the global variable I want to edit
        update_dict_with_edits(the_dict_object.the_json, changed_dict_system)
```

And it works if I take the recursion out and hard code which sub_system it is editing like:

```
space_system_dict["sub_system"][0] = changed_json_dict
```

But it doesn't work with the current setup. Does anything stick out as incorrect? Is it something about how I can calling the recursion is making it so that it is no longer the global variable argument that is being manipulated?

Comment: Well there are quite a few things that stick out as incorrect, ie your names: none of them match up at all. What is `changed_json_dict`? And what is `d`? And don't you want to actually pass your `sub_system` dict to the recursion in some way?

Comment: Whoops I was changing my actual variable names to make them cleared out of their main context and forgot those two. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Ah I just figured it out. I was because I was changing a name, not mutating a reference. Here is a good link with info for similar issues: http://foobarnbaz.com/2012/07/08/understanding-python-variables/